# Linq to Entities Date Part Optimization

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to create a drilldown based upon a portion of a date field for a website admin dashboard (from the Interval Analysis chart).

[image: Dashboard Charts]

[image: Drilldown]

```
var drilldownQuery = DataManager.DataSessions
            .Include("Location")
            .Include("Quote.Carriers")
            .Include("Drivers")
            .Include("Vehicles")
            .Where(session =>
                session.Timestamp >= Model.FromDate &&
                session.Timestamp < through
            );

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.DrillDown))
        {
            drilldownQuery = drilldownQuery.ToList()
                .Where(session => 
                   IntervalSelector(session) == Model.DrillDown);
        }

    public string IntervalSelector(DataSession session)
    {
        switch (Model.SelectedInterval)
        {
            case TimeInterval.Hourly:
                return session.Timestamp.Hour.ToString("D2");
            case TimeInterval.Weekday:
                return ((int)session.Timestamp.DayOfWeek).ToString();
            case TimeInterval.Weekly:
                return session.Timestamp.Date.AddDays(-(int)session.Timestamp.DayOfWeek).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
            case TimeInterval.Monthly:
                return session.Timestamp.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM");
            case TimeInterval.Annual:
                return session.Timestamp.Year.ToString("D4");
            default:
                return session.Timestamp.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        }
    }
```

Of course this performs very poorly with large date ranges. I'm hoping to avoid the "ToList()" call so that the drill down criteria is performed on the database instead of in memory. And that's where I'm stuck, specifically when drilling down into hourly and weekday criteria.

IntervalSelector is also used for grouping the graph query as well as the drill down. I'm open to using a separate selector for the drill down, whatever will improve it's performance. The graph query also performs a ToList, but performance is fine because it doesn't need the includes.

```
var graphQuery = DataManager.DataSessions
            .Where(session =>
                session.Timestamp >= Model.FromDate &&
                session.Timestamp < through);
```

I guess the better route would be to move the switch statement outside of Linq, like so:

```
switch (Model.SelectedInterval)
{
    case TimeInterval.Hourly:
        int selectedHour = int.Parse(Model.DrillDown);
        drilldownQuery = drilldownQuery
            .Where(session => session.Timestamp.Hour == selectedHour);
        // thoughts on this? any better way?
        break;
    case TimeInterval.Weekday:
        var selectedWeekday = int.Parse(Model.DrillDown) + 1; 
             // convert to sql dayofweek (Sun = 1)
        drilldownQuery =
            drilldownQuery.Where(
                 session => SqlFunctions
                      .DatePart("weekday", session.Timestamp) == 
                            selectedWeekday);
         // get a NotSupportedException here.
         // This function can only be invoked from Linq to Entities
         break;
    case TimeInterval.Weekly:
    case TimeInterval.Monthly:
    case TimeInterval.Annual:
    default:
        // handle these by adjusting the from & through dates?
}
```

Comment: This might be better received on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Keep in mind that anything performed in the linq statements that use your EF context will be converted to SQL.  So if you think the operation will be performed better outside of sql server, then I'd definitely recommend to keep those operations/manipulations outside of the linq-to-entities statements

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. I want this processed in sql server and I can't quite get there. That's why I'm asking for help. @JNYRanger

Comment: Which variable is your EF context in this code?  Is it DataManager?  Also, are you using lazy or eager loading?

Comment: @JNYRanger - Yes, DataManager is a subclass of the context. I am eager loading child tables ( insurance quotes, so the session, location, drivers, vehicles, carriers, etc). That's why I need to avoid a premature .ToList()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved this. Here it is for anyone else who needs it:

```
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.DrillDown))
        {
            switch (model.SelectedInterval)
            {
                case TimeInterval.Weekly:
                    model.FromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(model.DrillDown,"yyyy/MM/dd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    model.ThroughDate = model.FromDate.AddDays(6);
                    break;
                case TimeInterval.Monthly:
                    model.FromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(model.DrillDown+"/01", "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    model.ThroughDate = model.FromDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
                    break;
                case TimeInterval.Annual:
                    model.FromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(model.DrillDown + "/01/01", "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    model.ThroughDate = model.FromDate.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1);
                    break;
                case TimeInterval.Daily:
                    model.FromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(model.DrillDown, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    model.ThroughDate = model.FromDate;
                    break;
            }

        }

        var through = model.ThroughDate.AddDays(1);

        var drilldownQuery = DataManager.DataSessions
            .Include("Location")
            .Include("Quote.Carriers")
            .Include("Drivers")
            .Include("Vehicles")
            .Where(session =>
                session.Timestamp >= model.FromDate &&
                session.Timestamp < through
            );

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.DrillDown))
        {
            switch (model.SelectedInterval)
            {
                case TimeInterval.Hourly:
                    int selectedHour = int.Parse(model.DrillDown);
                    drilldownQuery = drilldownQuery.Where(session => session.Timestamp.Hour == selectedHour);
                    break;
                case TimeInterval.Weekday:
                    var selectedWeekday = (DayOfWeek) int.Parse(model.DrillDown);
                    drilldownQuery =
                        drilldownQuery.Where(
                            session => session.Timestamp.DayOfWeek == selectedWeekday);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return drilldownQuery;

    }
```

Comment: haha i was just about to post a comment with a suggestion to do something very similar, but you beat me to it.  Nice job!